# Send attachment and message using table by mail in php

Tags: php

I want to attach a generated pdf file and a  Thank you message with a contents generated in the pdf in the body of mail done by using html table.
Attaching and mailing the file works fine. But the thank you message and details doesn't appear in the body of mail. Here is code.

```
$pdf->Output('abc-REG.pdf', 'I');
$to = 'abc@gmail.com, ' . $email;
$subject = 'ABC :: ACTIVATION';
$repEmail = 'abc@gmail.com';
$fileName = 'abc-REG.pdf';
$fileatt = $pdf->Output($fileName, 'E');
$attachment = chunk_split($fileatt);
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());
$headers = 'From: ABC <'.$repEmail.'>'.$eol;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://google.com/images/logo.png"  /><br/>';
$message .= "Thanks for Activation. Your online registration number is A0". mysql_insert_id() ". "
    $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mobile']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Organisation Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['cname']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>" .  strip_tags($_POST['Address']) . "</td></tr>"; 
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>".$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $attachment.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator."--";
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "Email sent";
}
else {
    echo "Email failed";
}
```

Comment: You've tagged it, and I'd suggest using it, PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your missing the first separator due to a missing period:

```
$message = "--".$separator.$eol; <--- This separator 

$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;  <--- and this encoding is dropped

$message = '<html><body>';  <--- due to missing period here (= not .=)

$message .= '<img src="http://google.com/images/logo.png"  /><br/>';
```

#### EDIT

Ok, it also seems like the HTML is missing from its proper place where content type is HTML:

```
...
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://google.com/images/logo.png"  /><br/>';
$message .= "Thanks for Activation. Your online registration number is A0". mysql_insert_id() ". "
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mobile']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Organisation Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['cname']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>" .  strip_tags($_POST['Address']) . "</td></tr>"; 
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>".$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;

//missing content here

$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
...
```

Like so:

```
...
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' .$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$message = "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$message .= '<html><body>';
$message .= '<img src="http://google.com/images/logo.png"  /><br/>';
$message .= "Thanks for Activation. Your online registration number is A0". mysql_insert_id() ". "
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mobile']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Organisation Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['cname']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>" .  strip_tags($_POST['Address']) . "</td></tr>"; 
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>".$eol;
$message .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$fileName."\"".$eol; 
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
...
```

By the way? Do you need the 7-bit encoded part? Perhaps mark it as content type text/plain and provide a markup free, plain text version of the mail? You'd be surprised to see just how may people don't or won't support HTML e-mails.

#### EDIT 2

Just noticed that you are using PHP_EOL as line ending. If this is sent from a non-windows system, you might get the wrong line endings. Separate the lines with `"\r\n"`.

Also try setting this line as the first in body, rather than header:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
```

Change it to:

```
$message = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
...
```

You might also need to mix content type mixed with content type alternative. See here: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

Comment: I tried using $message .= '<html><body>'; Still it is same

Comment: @user6582683 If you try to move the HTML from the 7-bit part to the part marked above?

Comment: If i move HTML from 7-bit to the part marked. It is still the same body of email doesnt appear

Comment: @user6582683 Care to try again with the last edit? Edit based on this article: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php